# Allocating Memory for a Structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have done some research on allocating memory for a struct already on stackoverflow and the answers that i found did not work for me. With that said, here is my question and problem. For the most part a majority of them had the same bit of code that i currently have. Although my compiler is giving me an error.

Problem: I would like to allocate the memory for a Struct(an array of structs) and not a Pointer(pointer to a struct). Below is the definition of my Struct.

```
 #define INIT_MEMO_SIZE

typedef struct Memo
{
   struct HugeInteger *F; 
   int length; 

}Memo;
```

Required Solution: Within memo struct i would like to dynamically allocate an array of INIT_MEMO_SIZE number of huge integer structs

Attempted Solution: below right at "malloc" I am getting an error stating "Error: An entity of type 'void *' cannot be used to initialize an entity of type 'HugeInteger *' this underlines the keyword "malloc" in red. Compiler being used is Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

```
// Creates and initializes a Memo Struct
Memo *createMemo(void)
{ 
    HugeInteger *ptr = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE); 

    if(ptr == NULL)
        return NULL; 

} // End of *createMemo
```

Question: What am i doing wrong or what is the proper way to allocate the array of structs?

Comment: `HugeInteger`  --> `struct HugeInteger`

Comment: In C++, you need to cast the result of `malloc` to the appropriate type.  I think MSVC enforces this rule in C with appropriate flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

malloc returns a void*.  You need to cast the returned value.

```
 HugeInteger *ptr = (HugeInteger*)malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE);
```

Comment: Not true in C (but maybe Rex is compiling as C++?)

Comment: it is a C++ compiler that can run c code and my source files are of the extension .c to indicate to the compiler that this is c code. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579894/compile-c-app-with-visual-studio-2012 for more info.

Comment: @Rex In that case it is *not* able to "run c" in any strict sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says that this code "creates and initializes a Memo struct" however, I see no place where it either creates or initializes a `Memo` `struct`. In fact, the function doesn't even return such a struct (unless memory allocation failed). Perhaps you want something like this:

```
Memo *createMemo(void)
{ 
    Memo *memo = malloc(sizeof(Memo));

    if(memo == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memo->F = malloc(sizeof(struct HugeInteger) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE); 

    if(memo->F == NULL)
    { // Oops, memory allocation failed.
        free(memo);
        return NULL;
    }

    // other initialization here -- perhaps set memo->length 
    // to some sensible value
    memo->length = INIT_MEMO_SIZE;

    // and return the new memo
    return memo;
} // End of *createMemo
```

Generally speaking, you should not need to typecast the result of a `malloc` operation in C. Indeed, doing so can often cause subtle issues that can be difficult to diagnose. So, frankly, if the **compiler** is complaining, this would suggest that you are compiling as C++.

*However*, you say that not casting results in `malloc` being underlined in red and having some kind of "error" associated with it. This suggests to me what what you are seeing is not a compiler error, but a warning from an overzealous **editor** (via Intellisense, perhaps in combination with the SDL checks that VS2012 implements) that's trying to preemptively warn you about what it perceives to be an issue before you even compile.